# User Testing: 5-second test vs. 8-second test

Tags: usability-testing

I'm planning a "User Testing" and one of the tasks is the 5 (or 8) second test, so I want to know which fits better in my interface.

I can't remember what article talks about the difference between 5-second test and 8-second test, can someone remember it?

Or, if someone knows the differences, please share it with me! :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's an article about the 5-second usability test:
http://www.uie.com/articles/five_second_test/

The 8-second test is an extension of the 5-second test that starts after a user finds the page through a search engine link. It's described in Chapter 9 of [When Search Meets Usability](http://books.google.com/books?id=mQx3M-DGa_cC&pg=PA153&lpg=PA153&dq=usability+eight+second+test&source=bl&ots=6B4qZy5Fj5&sig=drkN0bzRh7-pwqj3vbJZjiWZjvA&hl=en&ei=JuZBTfCvF4XGlQe0j_kf&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=usability%20eight%20second%20test&f=false), by Shari Thurow and Nick Musica.

By the way, register at [usabilityhub.com](http://usabilityhub.com/) and you can conduct a 5 second test for free (if you join the community) or instead you can pay for it as well.

Comment: hey! you are right!! i saw that in that book!

Thank you so much Roland!

Comment: Your Welcome! :)